# bundle --no-deployment not installing development and test groups

Tags: ruby, bundler

Even running bundle with the following line:

```
bundle --no-deployment
```

It still not installs the development and test gems. I don't have any .gem file under my vendor directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the file `.bundle/config`, which by whatever reason was setting the frozen option and removing the deployment/test groups from inside. I simply deleted the folder:

```
rm -rf .bundle
```

And everything got back to normal.